# Table headers are disportional in relation to the table width

Tags: html, css, html-table

I can't really seem figure out as to why my table header are so disproportional to the table width itself. It just doesn't make any sense to me. Help =\

Here's a fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/3ment/

I've attached a picture of the problem:

[image]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<style type="text/css">

/*------------------------------------------------------------------
Table Style
------------------------------------------------------------------ */
table a:link {
    color: #666;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration:none;
}
table a:visited {
    color: #999999;
    font-weight:bold;
    text-decoration:none;
}
table a:active,
table a:hover {
    color: #bd5a35;
    text-decoration:underline;
}
table {
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color:#666;
    font-size:12px;
    background:#eaebec;
    border-collapse:collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
    table-layout: fixed;
    width: 100%;
}
table th {
    border-bottom:1px solid #e0e0e0;
    border-right: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
    background: #ededed;
}
table th:first-child {
    text-align: left;
}
table tr:first-child th:first-child {
    border-left: 0;
}

table td:first-child {
    text-align: left;
    border-left: 0;
}
table td {
    padding:10px;
    border-bottom:1px solid #e0e0e0;
    border-right: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
    background: #fafafa;
}
table th, table td {
    padding: 10px;
    width: 200px;
}
table tr:last-child td {
    border-bottom: 0;
}


table tr:hover td {
    background: #f2f2f2;

}

#wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    border: 1px solid rgb(205,205,205);
}
table thead {
    position:fixed;
}

table td > div {
   overflow: hidden;
   white-space: nowrap;
}


</style>

</head>

<body>

<div id="wrapper">
<table>

    <!-- Table Header -->
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Task Details</th>
            <th>File Number</th>
            <th>Firstname</th>
            <th>Progress</th>
            <th>Vital Task</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <!-- Table Header -->

    <!-- Table Body -->
    <tbody>

        <tr>
            <td>Create</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>100%</td>
            <td>Yes</td>
        </tr><!-- Table Row -->

        <tr>
            <td>Take the dog</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>100%</td>
            <td>Yes</td>
        </tr><!-- Darker Table Row -->

        <tr>
            <td>Waste half</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>20%</td>
            <td>No</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td><div>Feel inferior</div></td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>80%</td>
            <td>No</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td><div>Some long text that shouldn't resize the box</div></td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>100%</td>
            <td>Yes</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td><div>Vow to complete</div></td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>23%</td>
            <td>yes</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>Procrastinate</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>80%</td>
            <td>No</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td><a href="#yep-iit-doesnt-exist">Hyperlink Example</a></td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>80%</td>
            <td><a href="#inexistent-id">Another</a></td>
        </tr>

    </tbody>
    <!-- Table Body -->

</table>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This may be your problem `table thead { position:fixed;
}`, I'm not sure what you want with such a kind of css position setting for the table thead.

Comment: Basically, as the user scrolls, the headers remain in a fixed position. This alone is hard to render properly.

Comment: See if [**this link**](http://salzerdesign.com/test/fixedTable.html) helps any.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to separate the header and the body of the table into 2 tables wrapped in 2 divs. I've updated the fiddle for your review, http://jsfiddle.net/3ment/3/

However, this technique isn't ideal because it requires pixel-by-pixel calculations and it doesn't support horizontal scrolling. If you are to apply this solution, you will have to change the widths of the `wrapper`, `table` and `th` accordingly to your web page.

The best and easiest way is to use a jQuery plugin, like the one user3393390 suggests.

Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add jQuery to it in order to make it properly. The reason is explained below. A really good plugin that will do your job is this jQuery plugin: https://github.com/jmosbech/StickyTableHeaders

On a side note you can't just put position fixed on your table header as the user may just be anywhere on the screen and it will just look out of the place. This has to be triggered via making sure if the table header is getting out of the screen or not.